# Flot pie chart get data from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, flot

Hi i am trying to retrieve data from mysql database to create flot pie, i've data looks like this

data in array

> $Array = array();
>
> $Array[0] = array();
>      $Array[1] = array();
>      $Array[2] = array();
>
> $Array[0]['label'] = 'Grade A';
>      $Array[1]['label'] = 'Grade B';
>      $Array[2]['label'] = 'Grade C';
>
> $Array[0]['color'] = '#89A54E';
>      $Array[1]['color'] = '#AA4643';
>      $Array[2]['color'] = '#4572A7';
>
> $Array[0]['data'][0] = array(1,700);
>      $Array[1]['data'][0] = array(1,500);
>      $Array[2]['data'][0] = array(1,600);
>
> echo json_encode($Array);

and this mysql

```
$server = "localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database = "db_test";

$connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

$query = "SELECT * FROM pie";
$result = mysql_query($query);        

while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $event_array[] = array(
        'label' => $record['label'],
        'color' => $record['color'],
        'data' => $record['data']
    );
}

echo json_encode($event_array);
```

my flot js

```
    $.ajax
({
    type:'POST', 
    dataType: 'JSON', 
    url:'data.php',
    success: function(data) 
    {    
        $.plot($('#Pie'), data, 
        {
            series: 
            {
                pie: 
                {
                    show: true,
                    innerRadius: 0.4,
                    radius: 1,
                    label: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 1,
                        formatter: function(label, series) 
                        {
                            return "<div style='font-size:11px; text-align:center; padding:2px; color:white;'>"+label+"<br/>"
                            +Math.round(series.percent)+"%</div>";
                        },

                        background: 
                        {
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            grid: 
            {
                hoverable: true
            },

            legend: 
            {
                show: false
            }
        });
    }
});
```

it won't display anything, does anyone can help me.

Comment: if i'm using data array pie chart showed, but if i'm trying with mysql doesn't show anything

Comment: Did your browser throw any javascript errors?  I believe in your AJAX call dataType should be `json` not `JSON`.